# Finding the median of every 3 rows in a data set

Tags: r, for-loop, median

I'm currently analysing reaction time data **on R**. For every block a button is pressed thrice. I have every block together in a data frame in R strecthing from Block 1 - Block 10. I would like to sample the column median of each block, and then use it to construct a graph detailing change in median reaction time over the blocks.

I will admit I am a coding novice and have struggled a lot with this. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Rory. We'd be happy to help, but with a text-only description of your problem, it's very difficult for us to understand clearly. Furthermore, without knowing the name of any variables, their types etc, it is impossible for anyone here to give you any working code. Please make your question reproducible by including a sample of your data. If your data frame is called `mydata` then typing `dput(mydata)` into your console will produce a copy-pasteable version of your data frame that you can then paste into your question. You can [edit] your question at any time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, some more details about how your data actually look would help a lot. But I'll take a stab at it regardless. I'm guessing you are saying you have all the values in a single column in a data frame, and need to group them by 3, and find the median of those 3 values, for each of 10 blocks. As long as the values are ordered by group the solution below should work. It just converts the data into a matrix, then applies the median function to each column of that matrix. Output is a list of 10 medians, you could plot these or do whatever else you need.

```
#simulate the data, you don't need this part
Values = rnorm(30,0,1) #30 random values (3 for each of 10 blocks), from simple normal dist


#Actual Solution
ValuesAsMatrix=matrix(Values,nrow=3)
Medians = apply(ValuesAsMatrix,2,median) # 2 indicates apply to columns, 2nd dimension
```

Even if this isn't the exact structure of your problem, the general solution of getting these values into either the rows/columns of a matrix by group, then applying a solution should work.
Let me know if this works for you, if not try to provide more context in any follow up questions on this.

Comment: The structure of the data is essentially a singular column with reaction times. I just want to find the median for every 3 rows.

Comment: Perfect, give that solution a shot then, let me know if it works for you. I think it should